# Integrate chartjs-chart-treemap with react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, react-chartjs

I would like to add a treemap chart from [chartjs-chart-treemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-chart-treemap) into my existing project that uses [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2).

I tried so far:

```
import ChartComponent from 'react-chartjs-2';


export default class TreeMap extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ChartComponent
                {...this.props}
                ref={ref => this.chartInstance = ref && ref.chartInstance}
                type='treemap'
            />
        );
    }
}
```

,but I can see following error when trying to render this component:

> Error: "treemap" is not a chart type.

How can I use chartjs-chart-treemap with React?

Answer (score 3):

the chartjs-chart-treemap library has to be imported to the component file

```
import ChartComponent from 'react-chartjs-2';
import 'chartjs-chart-treemap';


export default class TreeMap extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ChartComponent
                {...this.props}
                ref={ref => this.chartInstance = ref && ref.chartInstance}
                type='treemap'
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not able to get this solution working.  I get an error `JSX element type 'ChartComponent' does not have any construct or call signatures.`  Also, can you update this to use React's functional components instead of extends?